# Cannot access bios after dual-booting pop-os and windows 11

Tags: boot, bios, grub, bootloader, dualboot

So I installed pop os on my SSD and just whiped the whole thing. I then made a second partition for Windows because I have games.
When I booted up normally it would just boot straight into the thing first on the boot order, instead of showing the grub menu.
It did not really bother me but since today.
When I boot it up, the Gigabyte logo shows up, but the text saying how to get into the bios is gone, and when I press F12 nothing happens.
The problem is that I cant boot to a USB because I normally do that through the bios.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: You're probably not pressing the kay fast enough.